# ¿Como puedo borrar el rectángulo dentro del btn?

Tags: java

Disculpen
Tengo una duda al momento de ejecutar me sale esto[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El botón cerrar con un cuadro alrededor de cerrar, alguien podría ayudarme a quitarlo?

Codigo:

```
package proyectoSistemaVentasCocina;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Cursor;

public class DlgAcercaTienda extends JDialog implements ActionListener {

    private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
    private JLabel lblLineaBaja;
    private JLabel lblTienda;
    private JLabel lblAutores;
    private JLabel lblGianella;
    private JLabel lblMark;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel;
    private JButton btnCerrar;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            DlgAcercaTienda dialog = new DlgAcercaTienda();
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     */
    public DlgAcercaTienda() {
        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(DlgAcercaTienda.class.getResource("/imagen/iconoForALL.png")));
        setTitle("Acerca de Tienda");
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 328);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        contentPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 434, 289);
        contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        getContentPane().add(contentPanel);
        contentPanel.setLayout(null);
        
        lblLineaBaja = new JLabel("  ____________________________________________________________");
        lblLineaBaja.setBounds(0, 64, 434, 29);
        contentPanel.add(lblLineaBaja);
        
        lblTienda = new JLabel("Tienda 1.0");
        lblTienda.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 30));
        lblTienda.setBounds(139, 12, 169, 54);
        contentPanel.add(lblTienda);
        
        lblAutores = new JLabel("Autores");
        lblAutores.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
        lblAutores.setBounds(189, 104, 97, 28);
        contentPanel.add(lblAutores);
        
        lblGianella = new JLabel("Gianella Fajardo");
        lblGianella.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        lblGianella.setBounds(179, 143, 97, 14);
        contentPanel.add(lblGianella);
        
        lblMark = new JLabel("Mario Casa");
        lblMark.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        lblMark.setBounds(190, 168, 85, 14);
        contentPanel.add(lblMario);
        
        lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Juan Mujica");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(185, 193, 97, 14);
        contentPanel.add(lblJuan);
        
        btnCerrar = new JButton("Cerrar");
        btnCerrar.addActionListener(this);
        btnCerrar.setBounds(179, 241, 89, 23);
        contentPanel.add(btnCerrar);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == btnCerrar) {
            actionPerformedBtnCerrar(e);
        }
    }
    protected void actionPerformedBtnCerrar(ActionEvent e) {
        dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: porque querrias quitar lo que indica que el boton tiene el foco? en tal caso, dale el foco a otra cosa...

Comment: Y el codigo, tiene que estar en la pregunta...

Comment: El colega @gbianchi esta en lo correcto, me imagino que es un solo boton y por default tiene el foco para facilitar el click.  pero lo puedes deshabilitar y habilitarlo desde el swing control por ejemplo  private void jTusuarioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
 jPclave.setEnabled(rootPaneCheckingEnabled);
 jPclave.requestFocus();
    }

Comment: Muy posiblemente `btnCerrar.setFocusPainted(false);` hace lo que esperas ver.

Comment: @JohnnyTB Me salio con lo tuyo bro gracias :D, jaja si es que nada mas por lo estetico queria que desaparezca el foco.

Answer (score 0):

para que el boton este deshabilitado debe de cambiarse su propiedad cuando se crea el boton en el jframe

```
BtnCerrar.setText("Cerrar");
BtnCerrar.setEnabled(false);
```

y lo habilitas por ejemplo después de utilizar un jtext

```
private void JsTextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
 BtnCerrar.setEnabled(rootPaneCheckingEnabled);
 BtnCerrar.requestFocus();
    }
```